# Getting infinite levels of subnavigations

Tags: php, mysql, sql, recursion

I've got a SQL-Table containing an ID and a foreign-key assigning to the same table. I'm using this to manage the (sub-)navigation Points in a webpage via PHP.

[image: Sample]

*(page_id 6 should of course have a 5 for the page_fs, sorry for that typo)*

As you can see, if the page_fs equals zero it's the top level, if not, it is a subnavigation of the page with the same ID.

What's the most efficient way to get a list like this, using PHP:
Page 1
--Page 1.1
--Page 1.2
----Page 1.2.1
Page 2
--Page 2.1
Page 3

It should support an infinite amount of layers.

Thank you for your help

Comment: As mysql doesn't support CTE ( Common Table Expressions ) the type of recursive querying you need to do to generate menu structures based upon essentially a flat table gets very complex. Some rdbms have  `recursive` abilities built-in, without this you need to get tricky with the sql. Read up on CTE ~ https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=firefox&q=mysql+common+table+expressions#safe=off&q=mysql+recursive+common+table+expression

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm sorry but I just realized that my question wasn't explained that well. I don't need an SQL-Query but a PHP function.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most efficient way would be to also store `position` and `level` in the database. However if can't or don't want to do that, here is a way to represent your navigation in an array structure:

```
<?php

/* SQL: 
    SELECT * FROM `navigation` ORDER BY `page_fs` DESC, `page_id
  result in: */

$sql_result = [
    ['page_id' => 6,    'page_fs' => 5, 'title' => 'Page 2.1' ],
    ['page_id' => 4,    'page_fs' => 3, 'title' => 'Page 1.2.1' ],
    ['page_id' => 2,    'page_fs' => 1, 'title' => 'Page 1.1' ],
    ['page_id' => 3,    'page_fs' => 1, 'title' => 'Page 1.2' ],
    ['page_id' => 1,    'page_fs' => 0, 'title' => 'Page 1' ],
    ['page_id' => 5,    'page_fs' => 0, 'title' => 'Page 2' ],
    ['page_id' => 7,    'page_fs' => 0, 'title' => 'Page 3' ]

];


function buildNavigation( $pages ) {
    $navigation = [];

    /* this loop assign each page to its id as an index 
     * Initializing ['children'] is optional. You'll' either 
     * have for every element or only for those which
     * actually have children .*/
    foreach($pages as $key => $page) {
        $navigation[ $page['page_id'] ] = $page;
        $navigation[ $page['page_id'] ]['children'] = []; 
    }

    /* Bring every element as a child to its parent and unset its
     * top level representation. */
    foreach($pages as $key => $page) {
        if( $page['page_fs'] > 0 ) {

            $navigation[ $page['page_fs'] ][ 'children' ][] = $navigation[$page['page_id']];

            unset($navigation[$page['page_id']]);
        }
    }

    return $navigation;

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r( buildNavigation($sql_result) );
echo "<pre>";
?>
```

With that structure a simple recursive function could transport this structure into the desired html output.